# How to detect SwiftUI usage programmatically in an iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swiftui

I am working on a library for iOS, and i need to know if the application using the library is running SwiftUI or not so that i can handle things appropriately.

Is there a way to find this out programmatically in Objective-C?

Comment: What do you use in your code that depends you to the language of the outside user?

Comment: Some of the functionality of our product does not work in swift UI yet, and so i would like to log a message telling the user that SwiftUI was detected and not all features will work. Also, we sometimes show an overlay in the app and i would like to eventually show a swiftui overlay if i detect swiftui.

Comment: Also, i'm not asking about the language, i'm asking specifically about the UI framework "SwiftUI" not just swift language

Comment: If you are using a `UIViewRepresentable` or `UIViewControllerRepresentable` then put the logging code there.

Comment: I think the surest way is to check if the `rootViewController` is of type `UIHostingController`. (Note: I'm not sure how to do this.) A UIKit app usually has a Storyboard, but that's easily removed. Also, `info.pist` for UIKit apps has a key for `UIMainStoryboardFile` - but again, I'm not sure if that's as reliable as check for a `UIHostingController`. And remember, come Xcode 12 this can change.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i did this.

1. Get the root or key window of the application.
2. Check if it's class name contains "UIHostingController"
3. Also nil check for this: NSClassFromString(@"SwiftUI._UIGraphicsView")

You could also check for other swift ui classes but this has covered all cases so far.